# VBA 400 Error when trying to Delete a Named Range

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I want to delete all global named ranges in a workbook.
I have this code:

```
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 Then xName.Delete
Next
```

Even when I change the code to delete ALL named ranges, I still get the same error.

```
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    xName.Delete
Next
```

When I run it, only the first Named Range is deleted and then it throws a 400 error.  It doesn't move on to the next one.

Is there some sort of add-on or setting that I'm missing?  This code seems pretty straight-forward, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't think it's illegal 'cause if I replace the xName.Delete with a msgbox, it displays all of my global named ranges as expect.  The problem is NOT with the Instr() bit, it's with xName.Delete.
As I mentioned, even without the InStr() function it still behaves the same.

Comment: That's hardly the point.

Comment: What are you actually trying to delete? Is there a different pattern?

Comment: Please don't focus on the "!".  I've removed it and the problem persists.  So, clearly that is NOT the problem.  The "!" isn't actually in the name.  That just happens to help me find the global named ranges.  None of my Named Ranges have "!" in the actual name.  I copied that script from somewhere and that works to find all the global Named Ranges.

Comment: put a breakpoint in `If InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 Then xName.Delete` and once there type `?xName.Name, xname.RefersTo` in Immediate Window and press return
.

Comment: once in VBA IDE, press CTRL-G to pop it out

Comment: If you take a single case and use the actual name will it delete with   ActiveWorkbook.Names("THE NAME").Delete ?

Comment: @DisplayName, thanx :) Found it.  "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: @QHarr, I've tried that as well.  I still get the same result.  400 Error.

Comment: then try typing `?ActiveWorkbook.Name` and press return

Comment: @DisplayName - It returns the workbook name: "Book57" - Could the problem be related to the workbook not being saved yet?

Comment: try typing `ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count` and press return

Comment: @DisplayName ?ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count returns "48"

Comment: and all that Immediate Window output is while you're still in the `For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names` offending line?

Comment: Oh no... I was on the xName.Delete :(  Lemme move the break up a line and redo all this for ya.  `?xName.Name, xname.RefersTo` returns an error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167925/discussion-between-narfie-and-displayname).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a long chat and some trial and error I've found the problem.
It's actually two-fold.

The reason this code didn't work, seems to be because the first Named Range it found was an Excel built-in range which obviously couldn't be deleted.
This is the case with both code snippets

```
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    xName.Delete
Next
```

AND

```
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 Then xName.Delete
Next
```

Because both of these find that built-in Named Range "_xlfn.CONCAT" and tries to delete it.

I finally heeded @QHarr's advice and used a different qualifier.  Luckily all my Named Ranges in the Workbook Scope has "Master" in the name, so it was easy enough.

**So, the final solution:**

```
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(xName.Name, "Master") > 0 Then xName.Delete
Next
```

Thanx guys!

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to check the first character of the named range. Special ranges start with "_" (underscore).

The way I solved this was a simple check. And working backwards.

```
Dim xName As Name
Dim xNum as Long
For XNum = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set XName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names(XNum)
    If InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 And Left(XName.Name, 1) <> "_" Then xName.Delete
Next
```

In my case, I was deleting all names, so did not need `InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 And` but this is very similar.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Also... there's a small error in your code - you've left out a parameter in the Left function. `Left(xName.Name <> "_", 1)`

Comment: @narfie: fixed that typo.

Comment: @narfie: should work. Did you amend your code to work backwards? Iterating forwards through a collection and deleting items will generally not work properly because once you delete the first item all the other items are renumbered and you end up skipping items.

Comment: Should be `If InStr(xName.Name, "!") = 0 And Left(xName.Name, 1) <> "_" Then`  or the `left` statement isn't valid

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: Fixed - typo when fixing typo!