# Excel VBA code error '1004' while searching external links

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help. I found the attached vba code but when I run the code I am getting a very strange 1004 error. Could you please give an explanation or try to fix this error?
Thank you so much all!

```
' Module to remove all hidden names on active workbook
Sub Remove_Hidden_Names()

   ' Dimension variables.
   Dim xName As Variant
   Dim Result As Variant
   Dim Vis As Variant

   ' Loop once for each name in the workbook.
   For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

       'If a name is not visible (it is hidden)...
       If xName.Visible = True Then
           Vis = "Visible"
       Else
           Vis = "Hidden"
       End If

       ' ...ask whether or not to delete the name.
       Result = MsgBox(prompt:="Delete " & Vis & " Name " & _
           Chr(10) & xName.Name & "?" & Chr(10) & _
           "Which refers to: " & Chr(10) & xName.RefersTo, _
           Buttons:=vbYesNo)

       ' If the result is true, then delete the name.
       If Result = vbYes Then xName.Delete

       ' Loop to the next name.
   Next xName

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the text of the error, an on which line is it?

Comment: The code breaks when found the variable 'xName'.
Run-time error 1004
The syntax of this name isn't correct.
Verify that the name:
   -Starts with a letter or underscore
   -Doesn't include a space or character that isn't allowed
   -Doesn't conflict with an existing name in the workbook.

Comment: `xName` is all over that code - which *line* is highlighted when it errors?

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you! Error at:        If Result = vbYes Then xName.Delete

Comment: I don't know if it helps: I am running on Windows 10 with the latest updates and Office 365 with the latest updates.

Comment: So the error is after you press "Yes" in the Message box? What is the name in the prompt? Looks like the name is invalid, but then it shouldn't be there in the first place. The code in general works.

Comment: Name may be corrupted/invalid:  eg see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/vba-1004-error-syntax-for-the-name-is-not-correct/53dddb47-ea41-4ce4-bc04-1e03ce7a07ab

Comment: Yes! exactly! When I am pressing "Yes"

Comment: @NicholasHunter The Visible check seems to be there only to show the use whether it is visible or not, when choosing to delete it.

Comment: ..or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586064/vba-400-error-when-trying-to-delete-a-named-range   What is the name of the range you're trying to delete?

Comment: @TimWilliams here is the first message where I am pressing on "Yes"  -Delete Hidden Name _xlfn.IFERROR? Which refers to: =#NAME?

Comment: Then that last link I posted is relevant here

Comment: I will lose my hair with this error....

Comment: @ChristoferWeber   Any ideas?....

Comment: The answer in that second link by Tim. Try those work-arounds or make an error handler for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

These Excel built-in range names appear in the Excel name manager when using SUMIFS,IFERROR, COUNTIFS and other formulas.

There are a lot of ways around this, as suggested in the comments.
You can add either of these:

```
If Not xName.Name Like "_xlfn*" Then 
'Or
If InStr(xName.Name, "_xlfn") = 0 Then
```

first thing in the loop (don't forget to close it), or something similar.

If you for some reason still want to see it, you can add it to the delete if:

```
If Result = vbYes And Not xName.Name Like "_xlfn*" Then xName.Delete
```

Comment: I have added your 'if' in the above code I have posted and it WORKS!! Thank you soo much!!!